# Mercurial, feature branches

Tags: mercurial

Im reading Mercurial, the definitive guide, and it mentions that in large projects, its useful to have your project split up into feature branches. Ive drawn a quick picture of what i think is happening when you want to merge the Feature Branch with the Master Branch.

Is my  diagram correct + does the Feature Branch continue to exist? Im assuming yes.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The active named branch can be explicitly ***closed*** using:

```
hg commit --close-branch
```

This tends to be done if a line of work was not going anywhere. If you want to re-open a branch of the same name on top of a *closed* branch, you need to force that branch open again using:

```
hg branch <name> --force
```

However, they implicitly become ***inactive*** if you merge from your feature branch into another branch and the feature branch has no un-merged change-sets (as in, the last thing on that branch is the merge into another branch). The destination of this merge does not have to be the "mainline" in order to deactivate the branch, inactivity is purely based on any un-merged change-sets.

They become active again if you subsequently create change-sets on them at a later date. This tends to be the common situation, if you are working on features off-mainline and merging in frequently.

Do note that a *closed* branch is not the same as an *inactive* branch.

I'm sorry, but I couldn't really understand your diagram so I hope the above sentences make sense.

<sub>Also, do not confuse named branches with anonymous branches, which are when a single branch has multiple "heads".</sub>

Comment: Sorry for the sh-t diagram. Yeah ur explanation above makes sense, thanks. I dont understand ur comment about anonymous branches. I THINK i had read somewhere that its not wise to name the main branch (i might be wrong, let me check).

Comment: @HansRudel [Anonymous branches](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BranchingExplained) are simply when you start committing change-sets on a branch not from the tip change-set. This results in multiple "heads" (or tips). Most of the time these heads will need to be merged internally to the branch.

Comment: @HansRudel From what I *can* understand of your diagram, your understanding does appear to be the same as what I explain, so I think we're all good :-)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I couldnt find where i had read that, so i guess i was mistaken with my above comment. Yeah, its what i had tried to show in my diagram but I wasnt aware that branches could be closed or inactive. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. (+1'd ur ans n comments :) )